# Is it possible to transform the heat equation in cylindrical coordinates to a Cartesian-like form using a variable substitution?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Consider the heat equation in spherical coordinates (considering only variation in the radial direction):

$$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t} = \frac{\alpha}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2 \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial r}\right).$$

Using the following variable substitution,

$$\theta = r\phi$$

it is possible to convert this equation into a "Cartesian-like" form:

$$\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial t} = \alpha\frac{\partial^2\theta}{\partial r^2}.$$

My question is:

Is it possible to begin with the heat equation in cylindrical coordinates (again only considering variation in the radial direction),

$$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t} = \frac{\alpha}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial r}\right)$$

and, using a similar variable substitution, achieve this same "Cartesian-like" end form?  If it is possible, what transformation achieves this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the substitution $z = r\phi$. We have $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} = \frac{-z}{r^2}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial r^2} = \frac{z}{r^3}$. Then:
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = \frac{\alpha}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left[r \cdot \left(\frac{-z}{r^2}\right)\right] = \frac{\alpha}{r} \cdot \frac{z}{r^2} = \alpha \cdot \frac{z}{r^3} = \alpha \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial r^2}.$$

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  Since 'z' is a function of 'r', you would need to apply the product rule when evaluating any derivative containing a product or quotient of those variables.  For example,

$$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\frac{z}{r}\right) = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial z}{\partial r} - \frac{z}{r^2}.$$

If you continue with the example, the PDE will not be reduced to the desired form.

Comment: Thank you for kindly pointing out my mistake. Can I ask how you arrived at the "Cartesian-like" form of the PDE from the spherical coordinates form?

Comment: Take the (radial part of) the heat equation

$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}\right)$$

and apply the substitution: $\theta = r \phi$.

The derivatives of phi with respect to time and position, considering the substitution, are:

$$\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\theta}{r}\right) = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}$$

Continued in next comment...

Comment: $$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\frac{\theta}{r}\right) = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial r} - \frac{\theta}{r^2}$$

Substitute these derivatives into the original PDE and simplify:

$$\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial r} - \frac{\theta}{r^2}\right)\right)$$

$$\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial r} - \theta\right)$$

Continued in next comment...

Comment: $$\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{r}\left(r\frac{\partial^2 \theta}{\partial r^2} + \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial r} - \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial r}\right)$$

$$\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 \theta}{\partial r^2}$$

After some more research about my original question, I now believe that there is no known substitution to reduce the cylindrical equation to the desired form.  If there were such a substitution, there might be no need for Bessel functions to exist...